# PHP rest api display an array of values

Tags: php, api, rest

I am trying to display all the items from an API. How can i display in html or store them in variables. In my code

```
$api_url = 'demo API';

// Read JSON file
$json_data = file_get_contents($api_url);

// Decode JSON data into PHP array
$response_data = json_decode($json_data, true);

$result = array_values($response_data);


 var_dump($result);
```

but unfortunately i dont know how to display the datas in front

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you [edit] your question and post the code you already have? What does `$result` look like? How do you want to display them, as a list, table, cards?

Comment: i want to display them as a list in html

Comment: That answers only one of my questions. Use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over and output the items

Comment: how can i display only the `id` for example?

Comment: I have no idea, you failed to answer "_What does $result look like?_" so we don't know what data you're dealing with here. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: $result displays the json array 
array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(5) "55737" ["channel_id"]=> string(2) "58" ["sport_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["program_datetime"]=> string(19) "2021-05-10 21:30:00" ["competition"]=> string(21)

Answer (score 0):

i found a way

```
<?php
  // JSON string
  $json_string = '(API)';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);


foreach($obj as $row => $innerArray){
  foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
    // echo  $innerRow.' = '.$value . "<br/>";
    if ($innerRow ==  "thumb_url") 
    {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $value; ?>" width="280" height="360">
    <?php
    }
    elseif ($innerRow == "title"){
        ?>
        <?php echo $value; ?>
        <?php
    }
  }
}

?>
```